# Don't understand why this TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "dict") to list started occurring

Tags: python

I've used this code to help delete mass messages, but now for some reason it's not working.

Delete all messages from specific channel:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\test\OneDrive\Documents\mass.py", line 33, in <module>
delete_all(auth_token, channel_id, username1, username2, get_all_messages(auth_token, channel_id))

  File "C:\Users\test\OneDrive\Documents\mass.py", line 16, in get_all_messages
prev = prev + messages

TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "dict") to list
```

Code:

```
import json, requests, sys
print ("Delete all messages from specific channel")

username1 = "test"
username2 = "test#0001"
auth_token = "RWYFHyrtYRY.RYYR_jqj114452E"
channel_id = "345634345364"
delete_from_all_users = "False"

def get_all_messages(auth, id, last="", prev=[]):
    if not last:
        messages = json.loads(requests.get("http://canary.discordapp.com/api/v6/channels/" + id + "/messages", headers={"authorization": auth}, params={"limit": 100}).content)
    else:
        messages = json.loads(requests.get("http://canary.discordapp.com/api/v6/channels/" + id + "/messages", headers={"authorization": auth}, params={"before" : last, "limit" : 100}).content)

    prev = prev + messages

    if len(messages) < 100:
        print ("Got to end of channel at " + str(len(prev)) + " messages")
        return prev
    else:
        oldest = sorted(messages, key=lambda x: x["timestamp"], reverse=True)[-1]
        return get_all_messages(auth, id, last=oldest["id"], prev=prev)

def delete_all(auth, id, user1, user2, messages):
    print ("Trying to delete all messages in " + id + " from username " + user1)
    for message in messages:
        # print(message["author"]["username"])
        if (message["author"]["username"] == user1):
            requests.delete("http://canary.discordapp.com/api/v6/channels/" + id + "/messages/" + message["id"],headers={"authorization": auth})
    print ("All messages were deleted")

delete_all(auth_token, channel_id, username1, username2, get_all_messages(auth_token, channel_id))
```

I'm not sure what changed. The script worked. I ran it again a month later, got this error.

Comment: The JSON endpoint must be returning a single JS object (translated to a python dict) rather than a JS array (translated to a python list)

Comment: I'm actually quite new with this code. Would you be able to show an example?

Comment: Quick note for the future -- use the `{}` button, not the StackSnippet button, unless you're trying to generate an example that can be run in the browser (which is to say, snippets are *only* for HTML/JavaScript/CSS questions).

Comment: Side note: don't set `prev` like this, `def get_all_messages(auth, id, last="", prev=[]):`, as it evaluates the empty list *once* during the definition of the function. After that, the list will be non-empty on subsequent calls.

Comment: BTW, you might want to inspect the output to see *why* it's no longer a list -- good chance you'd need to change other code too if the wire format was updated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to keep the old behavior of having a flat list when the content received is itself a list, but also be able to append non-list received messages as individual items, consider:

```
if isinstance(messages, list):
    prev.extend(messages)
else:  # messages is not really a list!
    prev.append(messages)
```

Otherwise, if you just want to append the newly-received batch of messages as a single item to your list no matter what, that would look like:

```
prev.append(messages)
```

You can only use `+` with a list on the left-hand side if the thing on the right-hand side *is also a list*. The error message indicates that not to be the case here (the thing on the right-hand side, in the responses you're getting from the server today, is a dict and not a list).

Answer (score 2):

`messages` should be a list, in your case it's a dictionary concatenation should be `list + list`

If you need to append an `int` or any other single element, you could always convert it into a single element list using `[]` or directly use `append`.

```
prev = prev + [messages]
```

OR

```
prev.append(messages)
```

Comment: `append()` is going to be a bit faster -- not a huge difference, but it could add up in a tight loop (not likely to be the case in the current codebase, however, which is likely to be bottlenecked on network).

Comment: @Charles Oh! Is it. I did not know that. Thanks.

Comment: See https://gist.github.com/charles-dyfis-net/4fdea55579b2945e2ec4372f5a8c8bce for some concrete benchmarks -- it's actually a much bigger difference than I expected. (Java's garbage collector plays a bunch of games to make transient objects that are only momentarily needed very cheap; it looks like Python doesn't do so as effectively, so the cost of creating all the single-item lists adds up).

Comment: You're not compelled to -- it adds something useful, I think; there's just also value to having this comment thread discussion so folks understand the practical limitations.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy These comments might help people like me.